# Libresolv dependency for Alpine linux

Tags: php, oracle, docker, alpine-linux

I have Alpine v3.7 Docker image and to put things short, I am installing OCI8 extension for PHP.

When doing the `php -v` I get the following error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8.so'
>   (tried:
>   /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/oci8.so (Error
>   loading shared library libresolv.so.2: No such file or directory
>   (needed by /usr/local/instantclient/libclntsh.so.18.1)),
>   /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/oci8.so.so
>   (Error loading shared library
>   /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/oci8.so.so: No
>   such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

I can't seem to find what package do I have to install in order to make this work. I have seen that there is a `libresolv.a` (I have also searched [here](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=libresolv*&path=&name=&branch=edge) and see there is no `libresolv.so.*` file in Alpine by defaut) file in my `/usr/lib/` folder so I tried sym-linking it back to Oracle folder, however that does nothing, I am still getting the same error.

These are the packages I am installing on Docker container create:

```
RUN apk add --update \
    autoconf gcc g++ make libaio-dev libnsl gettext-dev automake libtool libc6-compat;
```

Comment: Alpine version is different and dependency missing is different.

Comment: The problem is the same "how do I use Alpine with Oracle Client" and the answer is the same "don't" :)

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that you are using instaclient 18.

Using Oracle instaclient 11 you only have to add

```
FROM alpine3.11

# Setup LD lib path 
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/instantclient_11_2

# Install Apline dependencies
RUN apk add gcc libnsl libaio curl unzip openssl-dev autoconf musl-dev

RUN curl -k -o /tmp/basic.zip https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wilo087/Oracle-Instaclient_11_2/master/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip

# Unzip downloaded library
RUN unzip -d /usr/local/ /tmp/basic.zip

# Link Libs
RUN ln -sf ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}/libclntsh.so.19.1 ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}/libclntsh.so; \
  ln -s ${ORACLE_HOME}/libocci.so.* ${ORACLE_HOME}/libocci.so; \

# The libnsl version installed by Alpine is the number two, and instaclient use the number 1 so, create symbolic link for number one
RUN ln -sf /usr/lib/libnsl.so.2.0.0  /usr/lib/libnsl.so.1
```

Comment: The problem with this is that 11g is very, very, very old.

Comment: Oracle database 11g is not the same that instantclient_11. instantclient_11 works with the latest Oracle database (12c), the latest Cx_Oracle (v7.3) for Python and the latest Oci8 (v2.x) for PHP.

Comment: And it's old ! There have been a lot of fixes, feature improvements, and new features in the client since 11g. The latest Instant Client (19c) will connect to 11.2 DB. Overall, once you've had to install all the necessary packages into Alpine, you have to question whether there is any significant size benefit that outweighs the advantages of using an improved Client stack and the business continuity advantages of a [supported OS](https://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=dblatest&id=GUID-3F647617-7FF5-4EE4-BBA8-9A5E3EEC888F).

Comment: Yes, you're right, but this is a solution until the dependency problem with Libresolv is solved.